What are the tax effects of setting up a SMLLC in the US for a non-resident?
Suppose I'm a non-resident alien in the US, who owns a single-member LLC in Wyoming state.

If I pay tax in my local country, is ITIN required to submit any form of tax?
What company affairs is tax related and required to do every year?

Does anyone know? I mean, a full picture on that.

LLC in the US is by default a "disregarded entity". It has no meaning for taxes, and makes no difference on your Federal tax return. Its existence is irrelevant for taxes.
This changes if you explicitly and deliberately elect to treat your LLC as a corporation (filing either the form 2553 or the form 8832 with the IRS). In this case the LLC is treated as a corporation for tax purposes.
If your LLC has multiple members and no corporation election, it would be a partnership, which would potentially require a form 1065 to be filed.
For a single-member LLC which is a disregarded entity - it doesn't exist for the Federal tax purposes.
You still may need to file the BOI report with FinCEN though (pending appeals).

Since LLC tax is the same as the owner, Is ITIN required for an NRA to file tax?

@daisy yes, if you need to file a tax return you'll need an itin. This has nothing to do with the llc

So the tax is passed to the NRA, the NRA need ITIN to file taxes. Thus a single member LLC owned by the NRA must have ITIN. Am I right about that?

@daisy no, the LLC doesn't need any tax id, and it wouldn't be itin if it did. Itin is only for individuals.

I figured out only Form 1120 and 5472 are required to file. But it requires only the total income and expense for the tax year. I'm wondering how am I going to pay the tax? Or am I only required to file the forms and it would be everything.
